# Is single sign-on for self-registering Digital Experience users possible?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, digital-experience, open-id-connect, self-registration

We have a Digital Experience that includes self-registration logic that, when completed correctly, goes ahead and creates the necessary Contact and User resulting in the welcome email being sent. The user can setup their password and so complete the process.

These question have now come up:

1. Can the self-registration result in a single sign-on user being setup in an external Identity Provider?
2. Can the external Identity Provider be an external Salesforce org that is enabled as a SAML Identity Provider?

From reading the documentation, I don't see a way for the welcome email to be sent from the Salesforce Identity Provider; does a (secure) custom Apex API have to be created to make that happen?

Here is an illustration of what I think may be involved including a number of question mark areas...

[image: self-registration]

Comment: 1. Sure, standard integration via whatever method is supported by the external identity provider, usually API call(s). 2. Any SAML-compliant entity will work, including the same or  different SF org. 3. Welcome email - there's [an OOTB option](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_customize_email.htm&type=5) but it falls short for many use cases, so it's typically custom.